# A wrong sentence

Tags: grammar

I just found the following sentence in an English grammar book:

> The sun, which is one of millions of stars in the universe, provides us with heat and light.

Is it correct? I mean doesn't it need a "*the*" before "*millions*"?

Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't need a *the*, though you could use one.

*Millions of* behaves in most ways just like a number, so you only need *the* if you are talking about some specific items, and wanting to identify them as such (eg *the three people* vs *three people*)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need "the". You could include "the", but it doesn't fit very well, because it seems too definite. That is especially true because "millions" drastically understates the number of stars in the universe.